# ADBannerContentSizePortrait not available on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, iad

I am adding the iAd framework to an existing application. The application is portrait only and iPhone only. Everything is running in iOS 6, both in the simulator and on an iPhone 5. However, it fails in iOS 5 both in the simulator and on an iPhone 4. It throws the following exception:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'currentContentSize must be one of the requiredContentSizes; 'ADBannerContentSizePortrait' is not in {(
    ADBannerContentSizeLandscape
)}'
```

The exception is thrown on this line:

```
iAdBannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
```

I see no way of displaying anything other than a landscape banner this way. I'm assuming I must have something configured wrong somewhere, but I don't know where, and find it curious that it works fine in iOS 6.

Any help here is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

UPDATE: I can't answer this because I don't have enough rep points. But I have it fixed:

Background: I'm using the Kobold2D wrapper around ADBannerView. It's class, KKAdBanner, is the one that is actually calling the line causing the error. It turns out, it was preceding this call by configuring ADBannerView to only allow landscape sizes. This was a configuration issue and I can resolve it.

Of course, now I don't know why in the world it ever worked in iOS 6 at all, but oh well :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this, but from what I'm understanding from the documentation you need to set the `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSSet *requiredContentSizeIdentifiers`
with all the value that `currentContentSizeIdentifier` could take.

And your exception is saying that in that NSSet you only have the one for the landscape.
The difference you are seeing could be due to a different default values in different iOS version. (I'm guessing)

[Reference here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ADBannerView/requiredContentSizeIdentifiers)